# Sort by color and output to another location

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm trying to create a vba function in excel that sorts a column by cell color and then outputs the results to another location. What I have is currently giving me an error

```
Function SortColor(colorSearchRange As Range, colorToSearch As Range, outputRange As Range)
Dim colorValue As Integer
Dim coloredItems(150) As String
Dim index As Integer

colorValue = colorToSearch.Interior.ColorIndex
index = 0
Set cell = colorSearchRange
For Each cell In colorSearchRange
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = colorValue Then
        coloredItems(index) = cell.Value
        index = index + 1
    End If
Next cell

Range(outputRange & UBound(coloredItems) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(coloredItems)

End Function
```

I'm new to visual basic. Any type of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *currently giving me an error* - what is the error and when does it occur (what line)? ... at first glance, this line `Range(outputRange & UBound(coloredItems) + 1)` is not proper sytnax for a range argument

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I'm getting the error "a value used in the formula is the wrong data type". Im not sure what line it's happening at though... I've gone through the debugger and it looks like the array coloredItems is building properly, however it is not properly being outputted to the outputRange

Comment: This is what Scott was talking about. You need to rewrite that final line, because the Range method is being called with the wrong type of argument.

I'd suggest `Range(outputRange, outputRange.Offset(UBound(coloredItems)))` which will give you all the data in a column starting at outputRange (which is what I think you were looking to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use something like:

```
outputRange.Resize(index) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(coloredItems)
```

also, you don't need `Set cell = colorSearchRange`, since `cell` is going to be set at each iteration of the `For Each cell In colorSearchRange` loop

finally your `Function` isn't returning anything so you can make it a `Sub`

all what above could result in what follows:

```
Sub SortColor(colorSearchRange As Range, colorToSearch As Range, outputRange As Range)
    Dim colorValue As Long, index As Long
    Dim coloredItems() As String
    Dim cell As Range

    ReDim coloredItems(1 To colorSearchRange.Rows.Count) As String 'dim your array to the maxiumum possible for the passed range
    colorValue = colorToSearch.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each cell In colorSearchRange
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = colorValue Then
            index = index + 1
            coloredItems(index) = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    outputRange.Resize(index) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(coloredItems)
End Sub
```